# Netty client acting as a service

Tags: network-programming, netty

I am currently working on a client-server application using netty, some of the clients are not going to be doing anything until they recieve a message. I have read the api and can´t find a way to do so. I mean I could try to have "in.readline()" on the main so it won´t end but it Doesn´t feel right.  Also could have endless loops but I don´t think its the right way either.

The question here is: is there a way to bind the socket for incoming messages just like the server having the main method ending?

```
    public void run(){
    EventLoopGroup group = new NioEventLoopGroup();
    try {
            Bootstrap bootstrap = new Bootstrap()
                .group(group)
                .channel(NioSocketChannel.class)
                .handler(new ChatClientInitializer());

            Channel channel = bootstrap.connect(host,port).sync().channel();
            BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
                            System.out.println("Inserte su nombre");
                            String nombre = in.readLine();
                            MyClientChannel canal = new MyClientChannel(channel,nombre);
                            canal.write("SM",nombre);    
                            in.readLine();
```

See that at the end I had to write "in.readline()" so the program wouldn´t end and the handler would be still up for incomming messages

Comment: Please try to re-phrase the question and submit example code. I'm afraid it is not very clear what your problem is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easiest thing to do would be to replace:

```
in.readLine();
```

With:

```
channel.closeFuture().await();
```

When the connection to the server is disconnected, the client will terminate.

You will also want to spend some time defining your client's life-cycle, so that the channel's state doesn't affect when your application is running and when it's not.